# String usage with {} in bash

Tags: linux, shell, ash

I have a kind of the following strings

```
str1="aaa.bbb."
```

and

```
str2="aaa.ccc"
```

I wan to call:

```
echo ${str1%.*}
echo ${str2%.*}
```

in order to get

`"aaa.bbb."` for `str1`

and `"aaa."` for `str2`

what should I use as expression inside `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
echo "${str1%.*}."
aaa.bbb.

echo "${str2%.*}."
aaa.
```